# Material UI tooltip custom placement

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, material-ui

I want to place my sidebar and card list tooltips at the bottom center of the page, at the same place.

Used `margin` but I can't get them to be at the same place except if I probably make a class for each tooltip and they are a LOT. Inline margin styles on tooltips affect children too so that's out of the question. With `position absolute` they still are dependent on the anchor. Margin would also not be optimal for responsiveness. And `transform translate` doesn't seem to work on them.

Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

why not just create a div at the center of the page where you want the tooltips to appear and put the tooltip there? You can control the tooltip text dynamically using state

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a div with position fixed at the center bottom of your page. Render your tooltips there using state and clear the value using setTimeout if you want a Toast kind of feeling. State could be set on hover of the element.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'll try to pass a hook to the tooltips inline classes, so that I can take advantage of it's functions for starters.